# Could someone help me identify this please?

Tags: identification

[image]I have no idea why it is growing in my inland suburban back yard.

Comment: Hi, Mysty Khaz! Can you tell us in what part of the globe does it grow? Maybe we can narrow down the possibilities this way.

Comment: HI Alina, thank you for answering I am in Sydney, Australia. Let me know if there is anything else that i can answer to help you.

Comment: @Alina I hope my answer helps?

Comment: @Muze Thank you for taking the time to post an answer and I also hope it helps 'cause I have no idea about this plant. We'll see what more knowledgeable people think about as I'm counting on them to vote.

Comment: Mysty Khaz are you able to: 1 provide a close up photo of the top and the underside of the leaf, and 2 comment on whether you have seen any fruit? To add more info to you original post, click the Edit button at the bottom of your question :)

Comment: Hi, I will get a photo today or tomorrow and post it. Away from home atm for new year. Happy New Year folks!

Comment: @MystyKhaz Happy New Year! By the way, have you got the chance to check if the sap is milky?

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of further information I would suggest the plant is Ficus benjamina, or Benjamin Fig. For a test that it is in the fig family pull a green leaf from a stem and see if it has a milky sap. If not, I am wrong and can delete the suggestion.

Ficus benjamina grows outside in Sydney; there are some examples in the Sydney Botanical Garden. Generally they are discouraged in small gardens because the roots can be invasive and destructive to paths and buildings.

Normally they are grown from cuttings. It looks in this case as if someone took some cuttings (or sowed seeds close together, or even root pieces) and planted them close together with the intention of later separation. Towards the right to the back close to the fence it looks like someone cut back one of the vigorous shoots.

Answer (score 0):

These are a type mangrove which can grow about anywhere abundant of water take notice of the leaves in theses examples below. Mangroves can grow on land a brush but not normally as a tree but I did find a dry land mangrove tree shown on the last picture. I cannot give you the exact species sorry.

[image]

[image]

[image]
https://outreachecology.com/landmark/lti_e013/